# Grails - Only get URL params

Tags: grails

I trying to make a dynamic URL mapping which you can pass any query within the URl. So at this moment in time I want to render the key/values of the query but without the controller,method and action information.

So when I pass person?name=Mark&age=60

it renders ['name':'Mark', 'age':'60', 'controller':'Person', 'method':'GET', 'action':'getPerson']

How am I able to get just the query's in the url and not the other information about the controllers etc.

UrlMappings

```
"/person"{
        controller = "Person"
        method = 'GET'
        action = "getPerson"
    }
```

PersonController

```
def getPerson(){
    render params
}
```

I've done the following to remove them from the render by doing this:

```
    HashMap search = params
    String action = "action"
    String controller = "controller"
    String method = "method"

    search.remove(action)
    search.remove(controller)
    search.remove(method)

    render search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to remove the parameters that you know about and do not want to see:

```
def getPerson(){    
    render params.findAll { !(it.key in ['action', 'controller', 'method']) }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome - I wish there was a better approach though but I haven't found one.